# Error when adding Facebook SDK to Android Studio build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk

I have tried manually adding a module and have followed a number of guides to add the facebook sdk. Nothing has worked! Currently, I am simply trying to add it to my build.gradle file but this also produces an error. Any help would be great! Have also tried it with previous facebook versions that others have reported working.

The error:

```
Execution failed for task ':Selfies:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Some more things possibly related to the error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.domelz.pix"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.8.1.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you please try clearing cache and restarting android studio?

Comment: @Eenvincible how do I go about clearing the cache? Thanks for the reply

Comment: File->Clear Cache & Restart? Something closer to that in that menu

Comment: @Eenvincible Have done File->invalidate cache/restart then chose to invalidate and restart. Took a while to load up again but presented with the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I suggest you remove your dependencies one by one then see if it crashes again!

Comment: Now, I see the problem - multiple dex files meaning you have more than one dependency conflicting; so remove them one by one and add them back one by one

Comment: @Eenvincible It is the facebook dependency which messes it up `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'` but I am not sure how to add it without it messing things up lol

Comment: Remove the support dependency and see what happens; AS should provide that for you by default

Comment: @Eenvincible oh wow...it was the support dependency that seemed to clash with the facebook one, very weird and very simple. Thank you!!! I have spent all day on this lol. If you could move your comment into an answer and i'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is a conflict in the support library used by the Facebook Android SDK and the Support library provided by your SDK!

If you are using the latest Android Studio, adding the support library (jar) is unnecessary.

Please try removing that support library from your dependencies clause and it should just fix your issue!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully this will help someone else if they come past the same error.

Comment: So we thought the same! @user3604505 would you mind voting it up or accepting the answer doesn't allow a vote up?

Comment: @Eenvincible I have accepted the answer, cannot vote up though, do not meet the requirements to do so.